# Comparing $\sin(x)$ and $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZDpa.png): Given $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = \sin(x)$, provide a characteristic that the two functions have in common and a characteristic that distinguishes them.

Hi, I'm having some problems solving this question. I have tried graphing it on Desmos but I can't figure it out. I would appreciate it if you could help me out here.

Comment: hint: one is periodic but...

Comment: Both functions are odd. In other aspects they are very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things these functions have (and don't have) in common, so you could give a lot of different answers. It might help to know what kind of previous knowledge you have.

For example, $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\sin(x)$ have in common that

- They're both continuous on their respective domains.
- They're both differentiable on their respective domains.
- They're both odd functions, i.e. $-f(x) = f(-x)$ and $-g(x) = g(-x)$.

For things they don't have in common, you have for example

- $\frac{1}{x}$ is monotonic decreasing (separately on the intervals $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\mathbb{R}^-$), whilst $\sin(x)$ is not.
- $\sin(x)$ is a bounded function, whilst $\frac{1}{x}$ is not.
- $\sin(x)$ has an infinite number of zeros, whilst $\frac{1}{x}$ has none.
- The domain of $\sin(x)$ is all the reals, whilst the domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus{0}$.
- $\sin(x)$ is periodic (with period of $2\pi$), whilst $\frac{1}{x}$ is not.
- $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x)$ doesn't exist, but $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$ does.
- $\frac{1}{x}$ is an involution (its inverse function is itself), whilst $\sin(x)$ is not.
- $\frac{1}{x}$ is an injective function, whilst $\sin(x)$ is not.

You can continue to list examples of many other things, but without a framework of what you're working on it's difficult to say what answer you should use.

Comment: $x^{-1}$ doesn't exist at $x=0$ and neither does its derivative, so your first two similarities are incorrect.

Comment: @VividKraig: $x=0$ is not on the domain, so your comment is incorrect.

Comment: I meant to say that each function is differentiable on their _respective_ domain. In other words, $\frac{1}{x}$ is differentiable on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ and $\sin(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. I'll edit my answer to make it clear. Thank you!

Comment: I like the point about involution.

Comment: @RobertLee You da best ma G, helped me a lot. thank you so much. Much Luv <3

Answer (score 1):

Both $f$ and $g$ are odd functions.

Provided that $x$ is real, locally you can distinguish the two functions by noting that $g''(x)=-g(x)$ and $f''(x)\ne-f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Words cannot express how grateful I am for your help. Thanks Saviour, Luv you <3  @William McGonagall